React native webview on Andoid: Assets not found
I'm developing a React Native application for an Android mobile version.
I'm using Expo Webview to use an HTML file with assets loaded inside like this <link href="../styles/style.css" rel="stylesheet"> for example (I also have a JS file that dynamically loads JS files as needed). I tried with the path <link href="./assets/styles/style.css" rel="stylesheet"> but same problem.
Everything works fine when launching expo run but when I build the APK my assets are not found because the name of my assets are hashed (like bf865d20386eaf619c.css instead of style.css) and put in another path.
My webview:
const [assets, error] = useAssets([require('./assets/webview/index.html')])
const [renderedOnce, setRenderedOnce] = useState(false)

    const updateSource = () => {
        setRenderedOnce(true)
    }
return (
    <WebView
        ref={webViewRef}
        style={styles.webview}
        allowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs={true}
        originWhitelist={["*"]}
        source={{ uri: assets[0].localUri }}
        onLoad={updateSource}
        javaScriptEnabled={true}
        webviewDebuggingEnabled={true}
        allowingReadAccessToURL="*"
        allowFileAccess={true}
        allowFileAccessFromFileURLs={true}
        useWebKit={true}
        cacheEnabled={false}
/>)

My assets is located at the root of the project. Project > assets > (js, css, images...)
In metro.config I've put all the assetExt I need:
config.resolver["sourceExts"].push("css");
config.resolver["assetExts"].push("assets");
config.resolver["assetExts"].push("css");
config.resolver["assetExts"].push("ttf");
config.resolver["assetExts"].push("html");
config.resolver["assetExts"].push("svg");
config.resolver["assetExts"].push("json");

In app.json:
"assetBundlePatterns": [
      "./assets/**/*"
    ],
...
"packagerOpts": {
      "assetExts": [
        "html",
        "js",
        "jsx",
        "css",
        "html",
        "svg",
        "ttf",
        "eot",
        "woff",
        "json"
      ],
      "config": "metro.config.js",
      "sourceExts": [
        "js",
        "jsx",
        "css",
        "html",
        "svg",
        "ttf",
        "eot",
        "woff",
        "json"
      ]
    },

I don't really understand how to do this. Could you please help me? Thanks in advance!
